# Help securing freestanding wood deck fence

Tags: wood, deck, fence

[image: Freestanding fence]

Disclaimer: I know it is broken and missing some slats

I reinstalled my wood fence and I need better ways to secure it. I cannot attach it to the aluminum sidings (on the left).

The 2 posts are screwed on the deck (2x6 treated wood) on 4x4 metal bases.

I simply use what I had on hand to secure it, but I need something better (cleaner, safer).

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: The right way is to replace the primary posts with longer ones and secure them to the deck joists below. Are you willing to do that? I'll show you how.

Comment: Instead of replacing the two existing post with longer one, use the existing post by removing the bottom slats to gain about 8" on the bottom to do what Isherwood is suggesting.